# Centralizer of element in group PSL(2,F_p)

Tags: group-theory

Is it true, that $\forall g\in PSL(2,F_p)\setminus\{e\}$, $Z(g)$ is Abelian?

I think that this is true, but i can't find simple prove.

Comment: That is not the «center of $g$» (that does not make sense, really) but the «centralizer of $g$».

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the centralizer of an element of order $2$ is dihedral of order $(p \pm 1)$, and is nonabelian when $p>5$. It's true for $p=2,3,5$.